# UnitTest - Wait expectation ignored with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I'm having trouble with with waiting in unit testing with latest XCTestCase features.

this is what I have

```
viewModel.getLocations()
let loaded = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
let dataLoaded = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: loaded, object: viewModel.dataExist())
wait(for: [dataLoaded], timeout: 5)
```

So I need to wait for Network loading to happen to continue, and it does wait. But it always get timedOut although, when inspecting my vars, the data is set.

In the end the test will succeed if I catch the result of the waiting and then proceed even if timedOut, but it's just a hack...

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to not use network calls while unit testing. This is what dependency injection with mock data is for.

I once did a talk on this and the example code can be found here: https://github.com/karnett/MVVM

To expand on your actual question - I use these two functions that were floating around the stack overflow universe once upon a time:

```
func wait(_ duration: TimeInterval, object: XCUIElement)
{

    //waits for condition to be met when changing views before continuing tests.
    _ = self.expectation(
        for: NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1"),
        evaluatedWith: object,
        handler: nil)
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: duration, handler: nil)
}

func wait(_ duration: TimeInterval, object: XCUIElementQuery, count: Int)
{
    //waits for condition to be met when changing views before continuing tests.
    _ = self.expectation(
        for: NSPredicate(format: "self.count = \(count)"),
        evaluatedWith: object,
        handler: nil)
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: duration, handler: nil)
}
```

and you can call them by:

```
let emailTextField = app.textFields["Email"]

self.wait(2.0, object: app.textFields["Email"])
```

If your view doesn't load by x time, the unit test should fail. Unit tests exist to ensure you 1) didn't break anything, 2) verify user requirements, and 3) ensure the user is having a good experience.

Comment: Thx for your answer!Yeah I know about mocking, and that's what I did for the rest of my viewModel class. However I wanted to cover this specific method with this test. I'm not testing my view controller here, so I don't have access to UI elements. I need to use NSPredicate to wait for vars and object to be set. Also waitForExpectations has been replace by XCTWaiter.wait()

Answer (score 1):

It's important to highlight that NSPredicate works with ObjC compatible objects, functions and properties that means that your object against a given predicate is evaluated must be a subclass of the NSObject type and tested properties or functions must be marked with @objc attribute.

```
class ViewModel: NSObject {
    var _counter: Int = 0
    @objc var counter: Int {
        _counter += 1
        debugPrint(_counter)
        return _counter
    }
    
    var _counter2: Int = 0
    @objc func counter2() -> Int {
        _counter2 -= 1
        debugPrint(_counter2)
        return _counter2
    }
}

func testPredicateFormat() {
    let model = ViewModel()
    
    let counterValue = NSPredicate(format: "counter > 5")
    let dataLoaded = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: counterValue, object: model)
    wait(for: [dataLoaded], timeout: 10)
    
    let counterValue2 = NSPredicate(format: "counter2 < -5")
    let dataLoaded2 = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: counterValue2, object: model)
    wait(for: [dataLoaded2], timeout: 10)
}
```